# Spark Job takes one hour to process 10MB file

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I'm new to Spark and I'm running spark job on EMR cluster.
It takes about one hour for job to finish.

In job, there is a code for reading the file from S3 (file size is 10MB) and writing it's content into dynamo db.

I don't understand why it takes so long to finish this task? I was expecting that it would be finished much more faster.

Here is the code for Spark job:

```
public class PopulateCovid19Citations {

    private static final String APP_NAME = "PopulateCovid19Citations";
    private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(PopulateCovid19Citations.class);
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PopulateCovid19Citations.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        // Building the Spark session
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = SparkConfiguration.buildSparkContext(APP_NAME);
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .sparkContext(javaSparkContext.sc()).getOrCreate();

        String fileLocationTest = "s3a://mybucket/WHOCovid19CitationsDatabase.csv";
        Dataset<Row> fullCitations =
            sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true").load(fileLocationTest);
        fullCitations.show(10);

        // Selecting only the relevant columns for our exercise
        Dataset<Row> citations = fullCitations.select(
            col("Title"),
            col("Authors"),
            col("Abstract"),
            col("Published Year"),
            col("Journal"),
            col("Study"),
            col("Tags"));
        citations.show(10);


        // Removing citations with null title
        Dataset<Row> filteredCitations = citations.filter(col("Title").isNotNull());

        // Building a RDD composed of DynamoDB writable items that matches the Covid19Citation table
        JavaPairRDD<Text, DynamoDBItemWritable> dynamoCitations = filteredCitations.javaRDD().mapToPair(citation -> {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = new HashMap<>();
            putStringAttribute(attributes, "citationCode", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            putStringAttribute(attributes, "title", citation.getAs("Title"));
            putStringAttribute(attributes, "authors", citation.getAs("Authors"));
            putStringAttribute(attributes, "abstract", citation.getAs("Abstract"));
            putNumberAttribute(attributes, "publishedYear", citation.getAs("Published Year"));
            putStringAttribute(attributes, "journal", citation.getAs("Journal"));
            putStringAttribute(attributes, "study", citation.getAs("Study"));
            putStringAttribute(attributes, "tags", citation.getAs("Tags"));

            DynamoDBItemWritable dynamoDBItemWritable = new DynamoDBItemWritable();
            dynamoDBItemWritable.setItem(attributes);
            return new Tuple2<>(new Text(""), dynamoDBItemWritable);
        });

        // Writing data to the DynamoDB table
        JobConf jobConf = SparkConfiguration.buildJobConf(javaSparkContext, Boolean.FALSE);
        dynamoCitations.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf);
        sparkSession.stop();
    }

    private static void putStringAttribute(Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes, String key, Object fieldValue) {
        if (fieldValue != null) {
            attributes.put(key, new AttributeValue(fieldValue.toString()));
        }
    }

    private static void putNumberAttribute(Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes, String key, Object fieldValue) {
        if (fieldValue != null) {
            try {
                Integer integerFieldValue = Integer.parseInt(fieldValue.toString());
                AttributeValue attributeValue = new AttributeValue();
                attributeValue.setN(integerFieldValue.toString());
                attributes.put(key, attributeValue);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("cannot convert " + fieldValue + " to integer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the configuration for building Spark context:

```
public static JavaSparkContext buildSparkContext(String application) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName(application)
                  .set("spark.executor.cores", "5")
                  .set("spark.executor.memory", "42G")
                  .set("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "4G")
                  .set("spark.driver.memory", "42G")
                  .set("spark.driver.cores", "5")
                  .set("spark.executor.instances", "25")
                  .set("spark.default.parallelism", "250")
                  .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
                .registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
                        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text"),
                        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable")
                });
        return new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    }
```

Im using EMR cluster with m6a.16xlarge (64vcore, 259GB memory) for EC2 instance types.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already inspected the EMR metrics to see if anything stands out? How long of the 1hr was the job actually running?

Comment: @jordanm I'm not sure how can I check that. I see monitoring tab in EMR console, but I don't understand what should I look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV schema inference is implemented as "read through the entire file and work out the type of each column". There's a bit of sampling, but its the same thing really: 1 or more HTTP GET requests to stream through the entire file *before any computation begins*

Ideally, move off CSV to a modern file format, such as Avro, with a well defined schema. If you can't do that, explicitly declare the schema for the csv file in your app.

This may not be the sole cause of your problems, but it will be the first bottleneck in the processing

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. This is constuctive suggestion, I will change that part with schema. Do you have any more ideas what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing else. maybe look at dynamo db performance -you may just be prepaying for very limited IO capacity

Comment: that was the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: what was the problem? schema inference or DDB capacity?

Comment: DDB capacity :)

Comment: ok, upvoted your answer. do still stop with the schema inference though

Answer (score 2):

I finally found what was the problem. In yarn log I saw lines like this :

```
 23/06/14 11:26:28 WARN DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer: Retry: 1 Exception: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; Request ID: TM68B1L448VTTOIVEJ2G77Q4TJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
23/06/14 11:26:29 WARN DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer: Retry: 1 Exception: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; Request ID: 2HRBEQ17BV6KHT7P4FDM4TGL3JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
23/06/14 11:26:29 WARN DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer: Retry: 2 Exception: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; Request ID: D5FESCOIUVRQ764RL80IM8FEANVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
23/06/14 11:26:29 WARN DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer: Retry: 2 Exception: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; Request ID: 9TFNUKUGKM12B1VTIQSGRD46C7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
```

The conslusion is that database was bottleneck in my case.
Seems like we exceeded throughput for the dynamodb table. To fix this I needed to change provisioning configuration for dynamo db.

Comment: for ingress stuff, using PAYG is good as it is dynamic and you don't pay when idle...

Answer (score 1):

If you do iterative operations with the same data, you should use `persist()` method to avoid redundant recalculation.

I would recommend persisting at least `fullCitations` dataset after its creation.

See more about persistence in the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Also, I would check the Spark configuration. You have a cluster with 64 vcores and 259GB RAM, but you declared 25 executors with 5 cores and 42GB RAM for each executor. I am not sure you need such a large amount of resources for every executor, but it may affect performance if your cluster does not have enough resources to start all executors.